# Jailing user in a custom directory upon login

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-14.04, proftpd

I have 3 users in my system:

- user1
- user2
- user3

I have installed proftpd on ubuntu 14.04. Using `DefaultRoot` directive i can jail users in a specific directory, e.g. /home/%u/test

But what if i need to set dir /srv/www/domain.com for just one user, e.g.: user1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pretty much trick it using mount --bind like this for the user you want in that directory

```
 mount --bind /srv/www/domain.com /home/user1/test/domain.com
```

Comment: Can't i create user for specific path with ProFTPD?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the optional group parameters for the [`DefaultRoot`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_auth.html#DefaultRoot) directive.  For example, assume that each of your users belongs to a group of the same name:

- user1 belongs to group1
- user2 belongs to group2
- user3 belongs to group3

ProFTPD evaluates the `DefaultRoot` directives in its config files in the order in which they appear, and uses the *first matching directive*.  Thus you might use the following config, to use a different `chroot` directory just for user1:

```
# Users in group1 will be jailed to this specific directory...
DefaultRoot /srv/www/domain.com group1

# ...while all other users get their own home directory
DefaultRoot /home/%u/test
```

The reason that group names are used by `DefaultRoot`, rather than user names, is that group names can be used to cover/handle a larger number of users at one time, rather than requiring many individual `DefaultRoot` directives for each user.

This is covered in more detail in ProFTPD's [Chroot howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html).

Hope this helps!